# set interface using php curl without root in CentOS 6.5

Tags: php, curl, centos

I want to using phpcurl to request an HTTP with my PPTP VPN

but I find out if I dont use PHP-FPM with root I will get a error "curl: (7) Couldn't bind to 'ppp0'"

and it is not safe to set PHP-FPM run as root. is there any other way to make phpcurl able to use ppp0 interface without to be a root?

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062697/curl-through-openvpn-or-pptp? If so, there are several other [results on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+curl+vpn) that appear to explain how to connect to a VPN with curl.

Comment: this one haven't talk  about my root permission case

Comment: Maybe you set up your interface wrong if only root can access it.